# Custom domain for heroku app

Tags: heroku, dns, hosting

I am having troubles with setting up custom domain for my heroku app.
here is my heroku app:

```
https://evening-beyond-1234.herokuapp.com/
```

and let's say it is my domain:

```
my-fake-domain.com
```

So I want my app being able at this domain.

I've added this domain to heroku app domains:

```
$ heroku domains
=== evening-beyond-1234 Heroku Domain
evening-beyond-1234.herokuapp.com

=== evening-beyond-1234 Custom Domains
Domain Name       DNS Target
----------------  ---------------------------------
my-fake-domain.com  evening-beyond-1234.herokuapp.com
```

And on the site where I've bought the domain I can change DNS, so I did this:

1) Type of DNS -> DNS from other hosting provider

2) 1st DNS server (*required) -> evening-beyond-1234.herokuapp.com

3) 2nd DNS server (*required) -> evening-beyond-1234.herokuapp.com

I put the same for the second DNS, because it is marked as required, so I need to specify two DNS.

It's been a few days after these changes and it does not work. 
There is also another option for changing DNS: extended DNS editor.
I can specify CNAME entries and others there.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? 
I am completely new to this area, it should be just a silly mistake from my side %)

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is incorrect. What you are doing is that you are changing the name server of your domain, hence moving the delegation to Heroku.

However, Heroku is not an authoritative name server, hence you can't delegate your domain to them.

What you need to do is restore the delegation at your hosting provider and, instead, check the documentation of your hosting/DNS provider to learn how to create an A or CNAME record to point your domain to Heroku.

Also note that you will not be able to point your apex domain (hence `my-fake-domain.com` to Heroku unless you use [one of these DNS providers](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-root-domain) that support a CNAME-like capability for the apex domain.

Regardless who you use, you can create a CNAME record to point `www.my-fake-domain.com` to `evening-beyond-1234.herokuapp.com`.

For `my-fake-domain.com` you either create an ALIAS/ANAME according to one of those provider documentation, or you redirect the domain to the www version.